# On booting my laptop warns me about failure of hard disk is imminent...can it be repaired or to be replaced..?

Tags: hard-drive

when I am booting my laptop (Lenovo G550) it gives an error message prior to that.. 
**SMART Failure Predicted on Hard Disk O:Hitachi  HTS543225l9A300-(PM)
Warning : Immediately back up your data and replace your hard disk drive.
Afailure may be imminent.
Press F1 to continue..**

Once it started, it runs smoothly, I also verified its status by running some  internal HDD tests by Hard Disk Senitel software..It shows no bad sector , no virus, no damage , normal temperature ... it suggests every thing is OK except its health...

Now my question is that then what is the wrong with it..?
It may be wrong with plates (dusty) or the read/write heads...then can I go for repair it or replace it...?

My system now reminds me every half an hour to resolve this problem since last 10 days...

Help me.

Comment: Okay, so, first I would have a question. Is your computer making any abnormal sounds? Squeaking, screeching?

Comment: Your hard drive can be replaced, but you will need to backup everything that you have on your computer (which I would highly recommend, your system is telling you something, and in this case, I would listen!). Also, if the computer is older and/or has an outdated OS, I would highly recommend replacing the computer. However, if it is still a good computer overall, I would definitely look into replacing it!

Answer (score 4):

SMART is notorious for *not* catching hard disk failures ahead of time; you've gotten lucky. If HDS isn't reporting a problem, well, I wouldn't trust it. If SMART values have gotten so bad the BIOS is nagging you about it, that drive is about to crash and burn.

Repairing a hard drive yourself is pretty much impossible. Merely opening the drive would unavoidably expose the internals to dust particles that will destroy the heads and platters in short order. Replacement is the only option -- and on most laptops, replacing the hard drive is rather easy. Usually they're tucked beneath an access panel dedicated to the purpose, that comes out with a screw or two. Keep in mind you'll have to then install your OS and programs onto the new hard drive, and migrate your data over from your backup.

Answer (score 3):

> Keep in mind you'll have to then install your OS and programs onto the
>   new hard drive, and migrate your data over from your backup.

That's definitely one way of doing it, and good for cleaning out all the flotsam & jetsam that's accrued in an OS over time. Another way would be attempting to image the disk, and then merely put the new disk in the laptop. [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) is a free and easy way of completing this feat.